# RequiredFieldValidator to allow single white space

Tags: asp.net

I have a RequiredFieldValidator  on a textbox that fires if no text is entered. But  it should  not fire if I  enter single white space.  Right now If i enter single white space it still fires RequiredFieldValidator  , is there a way around it. I am using asp.net web forms

Comment: Did you try Googling ASP.NET validators? If you did, you might have come across RegularExpressionValidator Controls...

Comment: Please help , I am new to asp.net. Can we use both RegularExpressionValidator  and RequiredFieldValidator on a single textbox

Comment: Absolutely. You need to invest some time in reading up on validators in general. You can also us a Custom Validator, per VDWWD's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CustomValidator. You then need to create your own javascript function to validate the input and assign that function to the validator as the `ClientValidationFunction`. You can make that validator as complex as you want, as long as you return a boolean with `args.IsValid`

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"
 ClientValidationFunction="checkForWhiteSpace" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
 ValidateEmptyText="true"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkForWhiteSpace(oSrc, args) {
        if (args.Value === "") {
            args.IsValid = false;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe add serve-side validation as well?

Comment: And as @IrishChieftain mentioned, you should ALWAYS do server side validation as well.